# How show checkbox checked data-img on list

Tags: javascript, php, sql, checkbox

I have this field

`<input class="red-heart-checkbox " name="photo[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-img="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>"/>`

And I would like to make a list of image with url image from the `data-img`  checked but I only have values with this code :

```
<script>
            $(function() {
        var masterCheck = $("#masterCheck");
        var listCheckItems = $("#devel-generate-content-form :checkbox");

        masterCheck.on("click", function() {
          var isMasterChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
          listCheckItems.prop("checked", isMasterChecked);
          getSelectedItems();
        });

        listCheckItems.on("change", function() {
          var totalItems = listCheckItems.length;
          var checkedItems = listCheckItems.filter(":checked").length;

          if (totalItems == checkedItems) {
            masterCheck.prop("indeterminate", false);
            masterCheck.prop("checked", true);
          }
          else if (checkedItems > 0 && checkedItems < totalItems) {
            masterCheck.prop("indeterminate", true);
          }
          else {
            masterCheck.prop("indeterminate", false);
            masterCheck.prop("checked", false);
          }
          getSelectedItems();
        });

        function getSelectedItems() {
          var getCheckedValues = [];
          getCheckedValues = [];
            
          listCheckItems.filter(":checked").each(function() {
            getCheckedValues.push($(this).val());
          });
            
          $("#selected-values").html(JSON.stringify(getCheckedValues));
        }
      });
        </script>
```

My result is on :

```
<li class="list-group-item" id="selected-values"></li>
```

And looks like this :

[image: result of script]

Is it possible to have url image instead of the value , or use the result with de database to have url image ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions in my opinion,

1. The one you already suggested, i.e. use a db call
2. try passing imageURL in value